# (Openmdao 2.4.0) 'compute_partials' function of a Component seems to be run even when forcing 'declare_partials' to FD for this component

Tags: derivative, openmdao

I want to solve MDA for Sellar using Newton non linear solver for the Group . I have defined Disciplines with Derivatives (using 'compute_partials') but I want to check the number of calls to Discipline 'compute' and 'compute_partials' when forcing or not the disciplines not to use their analytical derivatives (using 'declare_partials' in the Problem definition ). The problem is that is seems that the 'compute_partials' function is still called even though I force not to use it .
Here is an example (Sellar)

So for Discipline 2, I add a counter and I have

```
from openmdao.test_suite.components.sellar import SellarDis1, SellarDis2 

class SellarDis2withDerivatives(SellarDis2):
    """
    Component containing Discipline 2 -- derivatives version.
    """

    def _do_declares(self):
        # Analytic Derivs
        self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*')
        self.exec_count_d = 0

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, J):
        """
        Jacobian for Sellar discipline 2.
        """
        y1 = inputs['y1']
        if y1.real < 0.0:
            y1 *= -1

        J['y2', 'y1'] = .5*y1**-.5
        J['y2', 'z'] = np.array([[1.0, 1.0]])
        self.exec_count_d += 1
```

I create a similar MDA as [on OpendMDAO docs](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.4.0/basic_guide/promote_vs_connect.html) but calling SellarDis2withDerivatives I have created and SellarDis1withDerivatives and changing the nonlinear_solver for Newton_solver() like this

```
    cycle.add_subsystem('d1', SellarDis1withDerivatives(), promotes_inputs=['x', 'z', 'y2'], promotes_outputs=['y1'])
    cycle.add_subsystem('d2', SellarDis2withDerivatives(), promotes_inputs=['z', 'y1'], promotes_outputs=['y2'])

    # Nonlinear Block Gauss Seidel is a gradient free solver
    cycle.nonlinear_solver = NewtonSolver()
    cycle.linear_solver = DirectSolver()
```

Then I run the following problem

```
 prob2 = Problem()

prob2.model = SellarMDA()

prob2.setup()

prob2.model.cycle.d1.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')
prob2.model.cycle.d2.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')

prob2['x'] = 2.
prob2['z'] = [-1., -1.]

prob2.run_model()


count = prob2.model.cycle.d2.exec_count_d
print("Number of derivatives calls (%i)"% (count))
```

And , as a results, I obtain

=====

## cycle

NL: Newton Converged in 3 iterations
Number of derivatives calls (3)

Therefore, it seems that the function 'compute_partials' is still called somehow (even if the derivatives are computed with FD ). Does someone as an explanation ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this to be a bug (or perhaps an unintended consequence of how derivatives are specified.)

This behavior is a by-product of mixed declaration of derivative, where we allow the user to specify some derivatives on a component to be 'fd' and other derivatives to be analytic.  So, we are always capable of doing both fd and `compute_partials` on a component.

There are two changes we could make in openmdao to remedy this:

1. Don't call `compute_partials` if no derivatives were explicitly declared as analytic.
2. Filter out any variables declared as 'fd' so that if a user tries to set them in `compute_partials`, a keyerror is raised (or maybe just a warning, and the derivative value is not overwritten)

In the meantime, the only workarounds would be to comment out the `compute_partials` method, or alternatively enclose the component in a group and finite difference the group.

Comment: OK, I better understand the way it works. The question was a bit tricky because the intent was to explain students the impact of Newton / Gauss Seidel with / without derivatives, but starting from the same Component and MDA, therefore just modifying the choice in the Problem definition.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to ask what kind of use-case would need the capability to finite difference a component that had analytic derivatives defined, outside of the context of check partials. So it's mostly an illustrative case.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is to have an attribute (here called `_call_compute_partials`) in your class, which tracks, if there where any analytical derivatives declared. And the conditional in `compute_partials()` could be implemented outside the method, where the method is called.

```
from openmdao.core.explicitcomponent import ExplicitComponent
from openmdao.core.indepvarcomp import IndepVarComp
from openmdao.core.problem import Problem
from openmdao.drivers.scipy_optimizer import ScipyOptimizeDriver


class ExplicitComponent2(ExplicitComponent):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ExplicitComponent2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._call_compute_partials = False

    def declare_partials(self, of, wrt, dependent=True, rows=None, cols=None, val=None,
                         method='exact', step=None, form=None, step_calc=None):
        if method == 'exact':
            self._call_compute_partials = True
        super(ExplicitComponent2, self).declare_partials(of, wrt, dependent, rows, cols, val,
                         method, step, form, step_calc)


class Cylinder(ExplicitComponent2):
    """Main class"""

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('radius', val=1.0)
        self.add_input('height', val=1.0)

        self.add_output('Area', val=1.0)
        self.add_output('Volume', val=1.0)

        # self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')
        # self.declare_partials('*', '*')

        self.declare_partials('Volume', 'height', method='fd')
        self.declare_partials('Volume', 'radius', method='fd')
        self.declare_partials('Area', 'height', method='fd')
        self.declare_partials('Area', 'radius')
        # self.declare_partials('Area', 'radius', method='fd')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        radius = inputs['radius']
        height = inputs['height']

        area = height * radius * 2 * 3.14 + 3.14 * radius ** 2 * 2
        volume = 3.14 * radius ** 2 * height
        outputs['Area'] = area
        outputs['Volume'] = volume

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, partials):
        if self._call_compute_partials:
            print('Calculate partials...')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    prob = Problem()

    indeps = prob.model.add_subsystem('indeps', IndepVarComp(), promotes=['*'])
    indeps.add_output('radius', 2.)  # height
    indeps.add_output('height', 3.)  # radius
    main = prob.model.add_subsystem('cylinder', Cylinder(), promotes=['*'])

    # setup the optimization
    prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()

    prob.model.add_design_var('radius', lower=0.5, upper=5.)
    prob.model.add_design_var('height', lower=0.5, upper=5.)
    prob.model.add_objective('Area')
    prob.model.add_constraint('Volume', lower=10.)

    prob.setup()
    prob.run_driver()
    print(prob['Volume'])  # should be around 10
```